# Tengo un código de JQuery que no me reconoce en Safari pero en Chrome si, que puedo hacer?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una web para mobilefisrt, hice este código para que no me "tome en cuenta" algunas funcionalidades de mi div (adentro del div tiene un modal que el usuario podría tocar y abrirse), pero el problema es que lo pruebo con chrome y sin problemas, pero cuando hago testeo con **safari** es como si no hubiera implementado nada, ¿alguien me podría guiar? Gracias.

```js
$(".card").hover(function () {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#" + id + " .cajaGrafico").removeClass('pointerEvents');
        $("#" + id + " .toggle").removeClass('pointerEvents');
    }.bind(this), 100);
}, function () {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#" + id + " .cajaGrafico").addClass('pointerEvents');
        $("#" + id + " .toggle").addClass('pointerEvents');

    }.bind(this), 100);
});
```

Comment: ¿Cuál línea del código no funciona en Safari? ¿Hay algún mensaje de error?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: no hay un mensaje de error, solo no hace la funcionalidad que debería, es una web mobilefirst, y cuando lo abre en el navegador chrome funciona de maravilla pero cuando lo pruebo con safari es como si no estuviera.

Comment: ¿Y qué funcionalidad debería tener?

Comment: el div tiene un efecto hover, y solo cuando el div esta en hover puedes acceder al modal, la parte de `$(".card").hover` detecta cuando el div esta en hover y entonces te da acceso al modal.